# Can I create a PHP function that I can call without parentheses?

Tags: php, function

I have a function that is effectively a replacement for print, and I want to call it without parentheses, just like calling print.

```
# Replace
print $foo, $bar, "\n";

# with
myprint $foo, $bar, "\n";
```

In Perl, you can create subroutines with parameter templates and it allows exactly this behavior if you define a subroutine as

```
sub myprint(@) { ... }
```

Anything similar in PHP?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

print is not a [variable functions](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)

> Because this is a language construct
>   and not a function, it cannot be
>   called using variable functions

And :

> Variable functions
>
> PHP supports the concept of variable
>   functions. This means that if a
>   variable name has parentheses appended
>   to it, PHP will look for a function
>   with the same name as whatever the
>   variable evaluates to, and will
>   attempt to execute it. Among other
>   things, this can be used to implement
>   callbacks, function tables, and so
>   forth.

Answer (score 11):

Only by editing the PHP codebase and adding a new language construct.

-Adam

Answer (score 10):

No, you can't do that in PHP.
Print isn't actually a function, it's a "language construct".

Answer (score 2):

Nope, PHP won't allow you to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a way to code a echoh to do something like:

```
echoh "hello";
```

and get:

```
'hello<br>\n'.
```

I guess one solution could be defining a constant and use it:

```
<?php
const PHP_BR_EOL = "<br>\n";
echo "Hello" . PHP_BR_EOL;
?>
```

Now I get:

```
Hello<br>
```

I know it requires more typing, but it is more complient with the examples on the PHP manual, and I use gvim with omnicomplete to save on the typing.   Also it would be easy to do a global search/replace PHP_EOL by PHP_BR_EOL.

Answer (score 0):

That can't be done with PHP. Functions you declare must be called with brackets.