# Creating functions without parentheses in PHP like 'echo'

Tags: php

I was wondering if there is any nice way of writing functions in PHP so that they don't require ( ) around the parameters.

Example:

```
function sayThis($str) {
    echo $str;
}

sayThis "hi!!";
```

Thanks,
Matt Mueller

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212604/can-i-create-a-php-function-that-i-can-call-without-parentheses)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I create a PHP function that I can call without parentheses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212604/can-i-create-a-php-function-that-i-can-call-without-parentheses)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There simply isn't. "echo" is more of an operator than a function, so you'd actually need to rewrite the PHP interpreter source in order to introduce new "functions" like those.

Edit: Actually, the more accurate term for "echo" is, as eyze has correctly pointed out, language construct rather than operator. http://php.net/manual/de/function.echo.php provides some more information.

Answer (score 6):

Simple answer, no.

`echo` is a language construct not a function, hence it doesn't need the parentheses.