# can I create a function without brackets?

Tags: php

all php functions need `()` in the end. However, `exit` doesnt need that.
Can I create a function manually, which I can later execute without `()` ?

Even more, If I have full access to php installation?

p.s. please dont tell me answers "exit is not function" or etc (My question is not if "exit" is function or not). I want to know HOW TO ACHIEVE like that.

Comment: exit is not a function. It is a language construct

Comment: This is answered in the docs - 'exit is a language construct and it can be called without parentheses if no status is passed.'. Your functions, though, are still functions and require the parens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I create a PHP function that I can call without parentheses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212604/can-i-create-a-php-function-that-i-can-call-without-parentheses)   and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773959/creating-functions-without-parentheses-in-php-like-echo

Comment: because they have parameters

Comment: @bansi According to the official PHP documentation `exit` is a function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php). `echo` is a function as well but I remember I last time I used them without ().

Comment: You are wrong. Read the second paragraph of the description in the document. BTW you can add edit modify language constructs as PHP is open source.

Comment: guys, some of your answers are not complete. You just say "it's not function", and i dont care if it is or not. I asked how to achieve that, not the question "is this a function or not".  thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

No you can't. You have to edit Base of PHP language to accomplish this.

exit , echo , print and etc are not function .

Comment: can you say how to edit BASE PHP language to achieve that?

Comment: It is not easy and requires a lot of time . But the only way . I do not know about this