# how to create language constructors in PHP like 'echo'

Tags: php, constructor

I was looking for creating some thing like:

```
myprint 'Hello';
```

In questions like [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773959/creating-functions-without-parentheses-in-php-like-echo), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212604/can-i-create-a-php-function-that-i-can-call-without-parentheses) i saw some people that saying:

- It is impossible
- It is possible

Actually i want to know can i create such language constructor that does something by editing php interpreter?

If yes, how?

Comment: Depends, how well can you code in C?

Comment: Yes i can code in C @apokryfos

Comment: https://github.com/php/php-src . Not sure on the specifics but `echo` is a language "token" `T_ECHO` which the interpreter probably knows how to deal with (somewhere). Can't help you any more. You need to dig into the code.

Comment: However, a thought occurs.... why do you want to do this?

Comment: i use var_dump every moment, and it's hard to typing it 
i want create `v $var;` for var_dump $var I've defined v(); function to do this but it's hard too @apokryfos

Comment: It's 1000 times harder to modify the PHP source so you can add v $var;

Comment: Do you know which file should i edit? @apokryfos

Comment: I do not know which file in particular, you need to dig through the code.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I've done for same situation (not actual *Language Constructor*, but useful for your question):

1) open php.ini and uncomment `auto_prepend_file` settings, and set like this:
auto_prepend_file  =C:\wamp\my_prepended_functions.php

2) put this content in that `.php` file:

```
if(!function_exists('v'))   { function v() { foreach(func_get_args() as $each){ var_dump($each); }    } }
if(!function_exists('vx'))  { function vx(){ foreach(func_get_args() as $each){ var_dump($each); } exit;} }
```

3) restart server and you will be able to always execute in any php file:

```
v($myVar1);
v($myVar1,$myVar2 );
vx($myVar1);
```