# Passing Arguments Without Commas and With Produces Different Results

Tags: perl

I'm trying to figure out why these two lines produce different results:

```
print($fh, "text"); --> 0x10101010 text (on STDOUT)

print($fh "text"); --> text (inside of file $fh)
```

When I have the comma I understand I create a list and when print only has a list it prints the list to STDOUT.
But, what is print doing when I don't have a comma? The result I want is the one I get without a comma.

This is strange to me and counters me expecting the one with the comma to work for my intended purpose. Code I usually see does filehandle printing with a line like "`print $file "text"`", but I want to use the parentheses as I find that more consistent with other languages. But, not putting a comma is just as inconsistent.

An explanation of the internals of "print" might help me understand. How is it getting the FILEHANDLE and LIST separate when there is no comma?

Docs: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html

Thanks!

Comment: Why should it be consistent with *other* languages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`print` isn't a normal function, and you shouldn't call it with the parentheses because you're not really passing a parameter list to the function.

The way I typically it written is

```
print {$fh} 'text';
print {$fh} 'text1', 'text2';
```

or not going to a file:

```
print 'text';
print 'text1', 'text2';
```

You ask "How is it getting the FILEHANDLE and LIST separate when there is no comma?" and the answer is "Magic, because it's not a normal function."

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't really consider that Perl would have special parsing for specific built in functions. Feel it'd be better if it was actually a real subroutine, but hey, I didn't write Perl. Guess I'm rattling my head here for nothing trying to understand some intricacies that don't really exist.

Comment: "Magic" doesn't quite do it for me...I'm actually curious how the arguments are parsed. Not sure where to look in the source code though.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I tried to look around on some git site for a few minutes and I got lost in it as well. Would take more time than I was willing to devote. Here's where I found the source: http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/tree

Comment: PHP handles `print` in the same way.  Here's a function I asked long ago about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212604/can-i-create-a-php-function-that-i-can-call-without-parentheses

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Look at [`perly.y`](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/HEAD:/perly.y) from line 781 on for the parser definitions of the “indirect object notation”. The `print` builtin is a list operator, called `LSTOP` in the grammar (or `FUNC` when it looks like an ordinary subroutine).

Comment: @amon Excellent, thank you! Now just need to review my Greek ;)

Answer (score 3):

In Perl, parens are mostly just used for precedence. It is customary to call builtins like `print` *without* parens – this emphasizes that they aren't subroutines, but special syntax like `for`, `map`, `split`, or `my`.

In your case, you have a variety of possibilities:

1. Leave out the comma, but this is error-prone:

   ```
   print($fh @list);
   print $fh (@list);
   ```
2. Use curly braces around the file handle (which I would suggest anyway):

   ```
   print { $fh } (@list);
   print({ $fh } @list);
   ```
3. Use the object-oriented interface:

   ```
   use IO::File; # on older perls
   $fh->print(@list);
   ```